# Нужна ли тут запятая? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение

*Если открыто данное окно, то при выборе этого пункта меню(,) фокус перейдет на таблицу этой программы.*
Нужна ли указанная запятая?

Comment: Зачем повторяться, Римма? Вопрос уже есть в заголовке.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова: не сообразил, что так не увидите.

Comment: Думаю, что в этом нет ничего страшного. Во всяком случае (извините,Артём), лучше почти повтор, чем тот заголовок, который оставили Вы: _Добрый вечер. Нужна ли тут запятая?_

Comment: *...тот заголовок, который оставили Вы...* — да, забавно получилось)) я и не заметил